# How to make Payment Gateway in magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Please provide any official doc or any demo mode for this i was refer to http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/ but no success yet

Comment: Have you tried something? Ask Magento related question here: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: Check this: http://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-gateway-api

Comment: Yes, i am tried it and also reas doc http://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-gateway-api but in magento 2 there is no app/code folder so, we integrate it? Please Suggest

Comment: You need to get into Magento 2 in detail before starting module development: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90466/why-code-folder-is-missing-under-app-folder-in-magento-2-stable-version

Comment: Get familiar with Composer and dependency management.

Comment: yes, i read composer and depenency management and download stripe by inchoo for magento 2 using composer vendor folder is download but when i integrate it is not running and their is no code folder i didn't understand there is no official doc from magento to develop payment gateway in magento 2 , it is better if you provide any demo mode for payment gateway zip so, that i will integrate it and understand the flow actually i am new in Magento

Comment: After doing this Magento frontend and backend page is blank when i check the console then threre is 500 internal server error i also check directory permission of var , app, pub is 777 so, there is no permission issue please suggest what should i do next?

Comment: Have you checked the server log?

Comment: Yes i am checked apache error log there is not any error please tell me how to check magento 2 error log?

Comment: You can see log inside: /var/log

Comment: i checked in /var/log/httpd and there are 2 files access_log and error_log and there is not error found

Answer (score -2):

make sure to add **js** and **html** files in web folder and deploy static content using :

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

knockout js uses these files to display payment methods

also this module has **USD** Currency hard coded in files , make sure that you change that as per your needs.

here is module's GIT for your reference : https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe

Comment: Hi Emizen. Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't give a step-by-step method. Also, I've come across the inchoo_stripe plugin. It doesn't help much just seeing their code. especially since most gateways do a redirect and stripe doesn't.